# Apps Script Write sheet name to cell on change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been spinning my wheels on this longer than I care to admit; I could use a nudge in the right direction.

I'm trying to write an `On change` trigger - when a user changes a sheet name, it updates to a cell on the same sheet (part of a dashboard on each sheet).

```
function activateSheet(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var shtNm = ss.getName();
  var target = ss.getRange("B2");

  if (e.changeType === "OTHER") {
      target.setValue(shtNm);
  }

}
```

Without the `if` block, the script works as expected.  I can run it manually on any sheet and the sheet name is set in cell B2 on the same sheet.

The trigger seems to be set correctly, confirmed by the full script working on Sheet 1.

However, as soon as I add in `e.changeType` it *only* works on Sheet 1 (the default active sheet).  I can't figure out how to make the selected/changed sheet active from inside the `if`.

Moving all of the code inside the `if` has the same effect - works on Sheet 1 but not anywhere else.

This needs to be independent of an explicit sheet name, ex `spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2), true);` so that it works regardless of what value the user inputs or which sheet number it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `getActiveSheet()` always returns `e.source.getActive().getSheets()[0]` for an onChange() trigger and changeType of "OTHER"

Answer (score -2):

*Edited answer*

I'm adding this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by @Cooper in the comments section. Thanks to the comment added, I'm able to confirm that when using `getActiveSheet() always returns e.source.getActive().getSheets()[0] for an onChange() trigger and changeType of "OTHER"`

I quickly tested this behavior using:

```
function logChange(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getName();
  console.log(e.changeType);
}
```

The function only shows the log for the change name made for sheet1, when changing the name for sheet2 it does not show the log.
[image]

I've been looking for a solution, however it looks like in this case when using e.changeType the behavior is expected. Nevertheless, having the option to use `.getActiveSheet()` and `e.changeType` returning the actual activesheet and not the default one would be a nice feature to have. If you have the time, you can open a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)

Comment: You don't need a new variable what the OP did is just fine. Try it on  sheet other than `ss.getSheets()[0]` ...you will find that it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Cooper, I just tested the behavior and of course you are totally right. I'm going to correct my answer.